# DOM Error in Ajax call only in Safari 9.0

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I have following code in my javascript

```
var _csrf = $("#csrf_token").val();

        var xhr = $.ajax ({

            url : 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
            type : 'GET',
            contentType : 'application/json',
            headers : {

                        "csrf" : _csrf
                    }
        })
        .done(function(data){

            alert('done');   

        })
        .fail(function(data){

            alert(data["statusText"]);
        })
        .always(function(data){

            alert('always');

        })
```

csrf_token is HTMl is as below

```
<input type="hidden" value=" {{ csrf_token }}" id="csrf_token" >
```

The result I am getting when calling this ajax call is Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12 if fail; block.

But when remove the csrf header, alerts in done block and always block is called.

Same code works fine in Chrome and doesn't throw any DOM error.

Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT

I have tried with a different filed 
In HTML:

In JS

```
 var c = $("#sessionId").val()
 var xhr = $.ajax ({

        url : 'http://ip.jsontest.com/',
        type : 'GET',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        headers : {

                    "identifier" : cookie
                }
    })
    .done(function(data){

        alert('done');   

    })
    .fail(function(data){

        alert(data["statusText"]);
    })
    .always(function(data){

        alert('always');

    })
```

still same issue

Comment: Why do you send csrf token as custom header and not as form data?

Comment: No specific reason, I am trying things and I am passing it as a header for now. But irrespective of csrf or not, I am getting the error. For example,introduced a new custom header as in edited question but still got the same error

Comment: Do you have any outout for `console.log(_csrf);` ?

Comment: Yes console.log(_csrf) prints  .eJxTik5JLEktycxN1YMxNIwMDE11FAwNgBhEG-oomFoAsbGOgpm5ibGxZqwSALQ8Das.wblYnJttn4qKhmSXCjz1wOUrkDg . I also noticed something I have warning called "Unexpected CSS token" in "bootstrap.min.css:5:57896"

Answer (score 0):

I've only just encountered this issue, myself, trying to use

```
headers = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

What I found, after a little bit of fiddling around, is that it is tripping up on the space in the header.  When I set it to:

```
headers = 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

it worked perfectly.  I've checked using different header content (random text, other valid headers), and it's the presence of at least one space in the header which is causing this particular trouble.  I don't know if you can reconfigure your headers to remove space(s), but it made mine start working again.

Unsure if you want to report it to Apple, given that it was working perfectly prior to the Safari 9 update, or perhaps something for the jQuery crew to look closer at.